# MySql: Date_add returns BLOB

Tags: mysql, blob, dateadd

i have the next query:
    `select avHours, date_add('2010-01-20', Interval 2 DAY) from tbl_available order by avHours;`

but it returns a blob field and not a date field.
when i see the value in the blob field, it's the right date.

how can i fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MySQL functions sometimes converts to BLOB.
You can fix it if you will cast result to a DATE type yourself, for example -

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD('2010-01-20', INTERVAL 2 DAY))
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(('2010-01-20' + INTERVAL 2 DAY) AS DATE)
```